# Is there a standard for the order of arguments printed in usage statement of a command line tool?

Tags: shell, command-line, coding-style, command-line-arguments

Greetings to my revered experts!

I'm writing a command line tool(similar to ls or cat or uname etc) and I was wondering if there's a best-practice to order the arguments in the usage statement.

I'm confused because, `ls`'s usage statement prints arguments in alphabetical order, where as `cat`'s usage statement does not!

Try `cat --help` and `ls --help`.

Can you refer me to some documentation too, if there is a standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, standard!  No, certainly nothing like that.  Pick your favorite, whichever looks nice and is organized well and is on everyone's computer already, and mimic it.

My opinions follow:

- I don't see any value in alphabetical.
- Order it logically, arranged into categories and put useful stuff first.
- Make sure the parsing engine is solid and "standard", preferably using someone else's.  Boost's [Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/program_options.html) or Python's [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) are good if they're in the right language for you.  Most other languages have some too.
- Make sure to include many examples that span the gamut of use.

Answer (score 1):

No standard so to speak but they should probably be grouped by usage patterns which is how most people would use them (not alphabetically).

As with all documentation and technical writing, you first have to decide on your audience.

For example, when you want to figure out how to get `sort` to ignore case, you rarely know already that it's `-f` (fold case, who the hell thought of *that?*). The most useful output would have a section on data transformation options (e.g., ignore case, treat accented characters as unaccented), another on key selection (e.g., which fields or sub-fields), another of key comparisons (e.g., alpha, numeric, collation) and so on.

In any case, the sort of person who already knows it's the `-f` option will also know how to use `less` to search for that option without having to page through reams of unneeded information:-)

In fact, I'd go one better. Have two possible outputs. Make the default a usage-based format but, at the top of that, make the first usage a way of getting an alphabetical listing:

```
pax> paxprog --help

paxprog - truly an amazing program.

    paxprog is capable of doing anything you want.

    Help output options:

        --help
            Usage-based assistance (default).

        --alpha-help
            All options in alphabetical order.

    Coffee-making options:

        --temp=chilled|tepid|hot|damnhot
            Selects the temperature.

    Blah, blah, blah ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There most certainly is a standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html.  Note paragraph 3: "Options are usually listed in alphabetical order unless this would make the utility description more confusing. "

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard, although there are some general conventions, which, I assume, you're already familiar with. It's not 100% though.